# Traversing multiple tables using sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following models:

```
accountTable = sequelize.define('Accounts', {})

walletTable = sequelize.define('Wallets', { 
'accountId' : { 'type' : Sequelize.BIGINT, 'references' : { model : 'Accounts', 'referenceKey' : 'id'}, allowNull: false },
'balance' : { 'type' : Sequelize.DOUBLE}

connection = sequelize.define('Connections', 
'accountId' : { type : Sequelize.BIGINT(11) , 'references' : { model : 'Accounts', 'referenceKey' : 'id'} },
'active' : { type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN }
})
```

What I'm trying to do is get all active Connections who have the same accountId as in Wallet and disconnect them.

This is how I'm doing it in SQL

```
select c.sessionName, w.balance from Connections as c inner join Wallets w on w.balance = 0 and w.accountId=t.accountId where t.active = 1;
```

I tried to do the same in sequelize using Relations and I'm not able to achieve it. I tried the belongToMany relation between the two tables, and I'm getting the error Connection has no relation Wallet.

Any idea how to solve this?

much appreciated

Comment: Can you please show us how do you model the relations? Because the query really depends on how the relation between tables work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have your relations modeled as

```
Accounts.hasOne(Wallets);
Accounts.hasMany(Connections);

Wallets.belongsTo(Accounts);

Connections.belongsTo(Accounts);
```

then you should be able to perform the query as below

```
Connections.findAll({
    where: { active: true },
    include: [{
        model: Accounts,
        required: true,
        include: [{
            model: Wallets,
            required: true
        }]
    }]
})
```